# How to retain test results of a program when an output exception occurs?

Tags: java

I need some input on the logic in my program.
The logic of my program basically looks like this:

```
- Ask user to select input file;
-- If exception --> error message, exit program;
-- Otherwise --> continue program, perform tests;
- After tests have been completed, ask user to select output file;
-- If exception --> error message, exit program;
-- Otherwise --> save results to file, exit program;
```

The problem is that if the user specifies an invalid output file, all test results are lost and the program terminates. I would like to give the user a second attempt at selecting an output file if he selects an invalid output file.

My output code currently looks like this:

```
public void printToFile() {

    JFileChooser outputFile;
    File outFileName;

    outputFile = new JFileChooser();

    outputFile.showSaveDialog(null);
    outFileName = outputFile.getSelectedFile();
    try {
        PrintStream outFile = new PrintStream(outFileName);
        // print results to file
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Can't be saved to this file! \n");
        System.exit(0); // exit program
    }
}
```

The only solution I can think of is to replace the `catch` block with the following code:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print("Can't be saved to this file! \n");
    printToFile();
}
```

However, if the user doesn't understand what went wrong, he might select the same file over and over, thus creating a (sort of) infinite loop.
Is there any alternative to this method, or a way to prevent the loop? Or is the method I came up with the way to go?

Comment: Why not use a while loop with the catch recurring the condition if File Not Found instead of System.exit()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a endless loop, but it is not. Its a wait for a external condition.
How long you want to wait is up to you. But in most cases as long as you allow the user to cancel out you don't need a max retries or timeout. The user will press cancel or kill your application if he does not want to provide the data. Or the app will run forever. Do you care?

compare

```
while (needsUserData) {
   askForUserData()
}
```

with

```
waitForUserData()
```

Just don't do recursion, you might run stack space =)

Comment: Thanks, the while loop is indeed a better solution than recursion. If no better options are suggested, this will be the way to go for me :)